# Phonegap Geolocation doesn't show coordinates

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, geolocation

I'm using cordova-2-7.0.
I copied and pasted the code page phonegap, but I don't see the coordinates on the emulator. What's the problem? Neither appears on my mobile.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>AjpdSoft localización</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Esperar la carga de Cordova
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova cargado
function onDeviceReady() 
{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}

// Localización encontrada
function onSuccess(position) 
{
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitud: ' + position.coords.latitude + '<br />' +
                        'Longitud: ' + position.coords.longitude + '<br />' +
                        'Altitud: ' + position.coords.altitude + '<br />' +
                        'Precision: ' + position.coords.accuracy + '<br />' +
                        'Precision altitud: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy           +           '<br/>' +
                        'Partida: ' + position.coords.heading + '<br />' +
                        'Velocidad: ' + position.coords.speed + '<br />' +
                        'Timestamp: ' + position.timestamp + '<br />';
}

// Si se produce un error en la obtención de la posición
function onError(error) 
{
    alert('Código error: ' + error.code + '\n' +
          'Error: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

</script>
</head>
 <body>
   <p id="geolocation">Obteniendo localizacion, espere por favor...</p>
  </body> </html>
 `
```

Answer (score 1):

First off all your cordova version is deprecated. 3.5 is the actual one and 2.7 is very old. So upgrade your cordova Version to the latest stable release.

After that you should build a total new project like this:

- `cd ~/desktop`
- `cordova create test com.test.com test`
- `cd test`
- `cordova platform add android` (or iOS or anything else)
- `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation`
- `cordova build`

after that you open your project, modifie the index to what you want it to look like, and paste this code into it:

```
// onSuccess Callback
// This method accepts a Position object, which contains the
// current GPS coordinates
//
var onSuccess = function(position) {
    alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
          'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
          'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
          'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
          'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
          'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
          'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
          'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
};

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

This is the full example from the cordova geolocation plugin which can be found over here [Cordova Geolocation Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/blob/master/doc/index.md)

Comment: I do not have the plugin installed, I necesto for cordova version 2.7? He believed it was from version 3.0.

Comment: ...i don't understand what you mean because of your english.

Comment: Sorry for my english :). Got version 2.7 installed in eclipse when I go to the page in phonegap zip version is up to 2.9, I download phonegap eclipse 3 for zip?

Comment: Download Cordova from its homepage over here -> http://cordova.apache.org/#download after that, follow this guide to set up cordova the right way -> http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface and then you start with my introduction above.

Comment: Does you emulator have gps?

Comment: You should be running the latest, since this uses the WebView Geolocation code, which is far more tested than the old Cordova plugin, and is compliant with the W3C spec.  That said, you need to provide mock locations through the emulator to have coordinates.